# RabbitMQ and Spring Java Running In The Same Docker Container

Tags: java, spring, docker, rabbitmq

I'm trying to figure out how to run RabbitMQ that installs the Auth Plugin and a Java Netflix Sidecar in one container.

So far I have this `Dockerfile` but it doesn't work:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.8.2-management

COPY rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

FROM openjdk:14-alpine

#make working directory /
WORKDIR /

#add logging service into workdir
ADD demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

#expose port
EXPOSE 5678

#run sidecar and rabbit service
CMD ["sh", "-c", "rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_auth_backend_http; rabbitmq-server", "java", "-jar", "demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Do I need a bash script in my case?